# How to use run_in_executor right?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I try to use `run_in_executor` and have some questions. Here is code (basically copypast from docs)

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures


def cpu_bound(val):
    # CPU-bound operations will block the event loop:
    # in general it is preferable to run them in a
    # process pool.
    print(f'Start task: {val}')
    sum(i * i for i in range(10 ** 7))
    print(f'End task: {val}')


async def async_task(val):
    print(f'Start async task: {val}')
    while True:
        print(f'Tick: {val}')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    ## Options:

    for i in range(5):
        loop.create_task(async_task(i))

    # 1. Run in the default loop's executor:
    # for i in range(10):
    #     loop.run_in_executor(
    #         None, cpu_bound, i)
    # print('default thread pool')

    # 2. Run in a custom thread pool:
    # with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as pool:
    #     for i in range(10):
    #         loop.run_in_executor(
    #             pool, cpu_bound, i)
    #     print('custom thread pool')

    # 3. Run in a custom process pool:
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers = 10) as pool:
        for i in range(10):
            loop.run_in_executor(
                pool, cpu_bound, i)
        print('custom process pool')

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Case 1: `run_in_executor` where `executor` is `None`:
`async_task`'s execute in the same time as `cpu_bound`'s execute.

In other cases `async_task`'s will execute after `cpu_bound`'s are done.
I thought when we use `ProcessPoolExecutor` tasks shouldn't block loop. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> In other cases `async_task`'s will execute after `cpu_bound`'s are done. I thought when we use `ProcessPoolExecutor` tasks shouldn't block loop. Where am I wrong?

The problem is that `with XXXPoolExecutor()` shuts down the pool at the end of the `with` block. Pool shutdown waits for the pending tasks to finish, which blocks the event loop and is incompatible with asyncio. Since your first variant doesn't involve a `with` statement, it doesn't have this issue.

The solution is simply to remove the `with` statement and create the pool once (for example at top-level or in `main()`), and just *use* it in the function. If you want to, you can explicitly shut down the pool by calling `pool.shutdown()` after `asyncio.run()` has completed.

Also note that you are never **awaiting** the futures returned by `loop.run_in_executor`. This is an error and asyncio will probably warn you of it; you should probably collect the returned values in a list and await them with something like `results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)`. This will not only collect the results, but also make sure that the exceptions that occur in the off-thread functions get correctly propagated to your code rather than dropped.

Comment: I'm using asyncio to run requests.get() in a loop. Is it ok not to wait for the results of the loop.run_in_executor ?

Comment: @r2b2 This answer argues tht you should wait for them *somewhere*, so you collect the exceptions if nothing else. Not awaiting is probably not a fatal flaw, see if you get any warnings from asyncio. Also, if you really don't care about the result or exceptions, perhaps you don't need `run_in_executor()` in the first place, you could just call `executor.submit()`. The whole point of `run_in_executor()` is to convert a `concurrent.futures.Future` (returned by `executor.submit`) to an awaitable `asyncio.Future`. If you don't need that functionality, you can use the executor directly.